# Regex to extract line containing term

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been using this regex

```
/(?:[^ .,;:]+[ .,;:]+){3}(?:term1|term2)(?:[ .,;:]+[^ .,;:]+){3}/gi
```

to extract selected terms and the preceding and succeeding 3 words. I'd like to change the regex so that I extract the line containing the selected terms. The line will be bounded by \n but I'd also like to trim leading and trailing spaces.
How do I alter the regex to do that?

example input:

```
   This line, containing  term2, I'd like to extract.  
        This line contains term13 and I'd like to ignore it  
  This line, on the other hand, contains term1, so let's keep it.
```

ouput would be

```
This line, containing  term2, I'd like to extract.
This line, on the other hand, contains term1, so let's keep it.
```

See code to be altered below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<script>
var Input = "   This line, containing  term2, I'd like to extract."
Input += "        This line contains term13 and I'd like to ignore it."
Input += "  This line, on the other hand, contains term1, so let's keep it."

 var matches = Input.match(/(?:[^ .,;:]+[ .,;:]+){3}(?:term1|term2)(?:[ .,;:]+[^ .,;:]+){3}/gi);
 var myMatches = ""
  for (i=0;i<matches.length;i++)
  {
  myMatches += ("..." + matches[i] + "...\n"); //assign to variable
  }
  alert(myMatches)
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A suggestion: you could use word boundaries if your words aren't likely to contain special characters.

Comment: So...what you need, is to extra lines that contains `"term1"` or `"term2"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Asad points out, you can use \b for word boundaries, that way term1 won't match term13 for instance.

The regex:

```
^ *(.*\b(?:term1|term2)\b.*) *$
```

Should do what you're after. Your matches will be in the first (and only) capture group. Simply loop through them and you're done.

[See it on rubular.](http://rubular.com/r/4qtqECwlcW)

Comment: So close I could taste it [:(](http://rubular.com/r/8ODOh4qFo5). Ah but I see yours doesn't have some mistakes I made.